# JSON panel onClick event triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, stringify

I'm trying to use JSONpanel.js /example and docs can be found [HERE](https://github.com/afeld/jsonpanel), everything works fine but as default this plugin provide onClick event registration for JSON containing arrays or lists - this array is expanded only after event click.
But is there some way how to trigger onClick event or register another type of event - I need to all expandable links to be expanded after page is loaded not only after click on it.

Exmple code where click event is registered:

```
ExpandablePair.prototype.createTagInnerMarkup = function(){
var $expander = $('<a class="expander" href="#">');
$expander.on('click', $.proxy(this.onKeyClick, this));  
var innerMarkup = Pair.prototype.createTagInnerMarkup.call(this);
$expander.append(innerMarkup);
return $expander; };
```

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: If this answered your question don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expander").click()
})
```

If i understand your issue correctly this should expand all those anchors by class.  This should be done after the expand click event is registered.

Comment: Thanks for answer but this will not work - when you look on the [example page](https://afeld.github.io/jsonpanel/) there is no element like "expander", it is just some kind of variable in jQuery I think.

Comment: expander is the class on the anchor tags. in the console for that page enter `$(".expander").click()` and hit enter, both expand. (thats how i came up with the solution ;) )

Comment: In jquery `$('.something')` will do something for every element with that class.  That is how they are registering the event to every anchor tag in a single call.

Comment: Yeah that works, but maybe there is a problem with document ready function - elements may still not exists, or I dont know but when I added code you provied to code it did nothing. But many thanks for all your responses!

Comment: What is showing up in the console when you load the page?  Why don't you copy into your question your HTML that is generated on the page after you load. As well as where you are putting the document ready function. The reason I am asking is you have to ensure your html is generated before that click event will do anything.

Comment: I've added a link to example page and my code is exactly the same - after your response I've added <script>....</script> right before head section start. This is only difference between my code and provided link's example - that's the reason why source code was not attached.

Comment: No, without errors! I'tried to investigate for many hours but without success. If it's no problem for you, could you downoad the source from link I provided in my question and try to add document ready section into it? Maybe my enviroment is not corrent or I don't know what else can be wrong. Many thanks!

Comment: Now it's working - I didn't noticed that there is another ready trigger section, so when I added your code as a last statement of this section, it's working - MANY THANKS!

Comment: I was just about to comment there was already a document ready function ;) Glad I could help.